# Operator == not compatible with types address and function () view returns (address)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, staking

So i have this code that im debugging and so far i managed to get rid of all the errors but this one persists no matter what i do,maybe someone with more experience can see the problem clearly because iv'e been banging my head on this for 3 days now without any luck

```
function setPaused(bool _paused) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
    paused = _paused;
    // Function to pause the smart contract but require(paused == false) in all customer facing functions
```

Comment: How is `owner` defined? Please share the full source code as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: owner is inherited from openzeppelin i did not define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the topic, I'm guessing the `owner` is actually a function, and not a variable.

Therefore you need to call the function, instead of just comparing it. Change your line to:

```
require(msg.sender == owner(), "You are not the owner");
```

Comment: you are actually a beast,how did i not notice this before im so dumb,thank you so much for the help man much obliged